# Plotly: why does the axis label move when I turn off tick labels?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

The following code produces the first chart below.  Uncommenting the showticklabels=False option generates the second chart below.  Why did the x-axis label move to the top, and how do I get it back down to the bottom?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=["Apples", "Oranges", "Watermelon", "Pears"],
    y=[3, 2, 1, 4]
))

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=500,
    height=500,
    yaxis=dict(title_text="Y-axis Title"),
    xaxis=dict(
        title_text="X-axis Title",
        # showticklabels=False,
    ),
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: As the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/axes/#toggling-axis-labels) explains, this seems to be the default behavior. I have looked for a way to move the title of the moved axis but have not found one at this time.